# Mac does)n't show all files from a WIndows computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, mac, file-sharing, osx-yosemite

When I connect to a computer from a local network that runs Windows 7, I only see the "Users" folder.

But if I connect with my Android phone (ES File Manager) I see all the folders and drives like this: ADMIN$, C$, D$, IPC$, Users.

Why is the Mac not showing everything? I'm using the same user/pw on both

Answer (score 1):

That's because those are `shares` and not physical folders. The only "real" folder here is Users.

Comment: Can I get the Mac to show the shares like Android does?

Comment: @macosxsucks - Sure.  [Connect it](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13882?viewlocale=en_US) to the Windows computer.  But OS X is doing it correctly.